# How to Update status line according to UI

Tags: java

I am developing a rcp application where i want to add a status line and show message according to control selected in the view .(Eg- Suppose Check box is selected than status bar should show a message than it should show message that check box is selected).

I am using 
getViewSite().getActionBars().getstatuslineManager().setMessage but i could not update  the status line.

I mean that whatever text i set at beginning that things are not changing at runtime.

Comment: are you asking about desktop or web application?

Comment: *but I could not update the status line* --? what does this mean. Did you get any error?

Comment: no it is not showing error but it is not updating.And this one is a desktop application

Comment: I think we need some more code to find a answer for this question, if there is no exception in this line the error could be some where else too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vogella tutorial is a good piece of information on developing a rcp application. Check the following

1. [Acessing status line](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse3RCP/article.html#statusline) - on similar line you can also update it.
2. [Displaying message box](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDialogs/article.html#dialogs_jfacemessage)

Comment: I read that already but  the text in status bar is not changing

Comment: ok. rcp is complex one. Check for the proper bindings, maybe they are not correct.